# Oracle 11g: Joins

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

To get the blue area on the right below, I'm doing:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name
MINUS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name
```

[image]

Is there a better way, and if so, which one and why ?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t2.column_name = t1.column_name);
```

For performance you want an index on `table1(column_name)`.  This probably has the best performance of possible solutions under the most circumstances.

Although you can use `JOIN`s and set operations, I find this to be the simplest way to express this particular logic.

Note that set operations such as `UNION` and `MINUS` can have unexpected side effects -- particularly removing duplicates *within tables* as well as *between tables*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a difference the performance ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 T2
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1 on T1.KOL = T2.KOL
WHERE T1.KOL is NULL;
```

the condition where is 'deleting' all rows that got match. So in Result you have Right join Minus Inner join.

EDIT: wrong table names :) 
EDIT2: I think my way is better than @Gordon Linoff, since it is way easier to use hints. Our 3 diffrent way to get results could be executed by oracle with the same execution plan. But in my result is very easy to control hints :) ANd is very simple.

Comment: Thanks! It return indeed to return the same results as the `NOT EXISTS` approach of @Gordon Linoff.I can't confirm if your solution is better or not (not my domain of expertise) but I suppose others will. Still, up voted.